# помогите ДОБАВИТЬ новые данные в JSON файл (C#)

Tags: c#, json

У меня есть определённый JSON. Храниться на сайте: http://frzee.ru/Airline/Accounts.json . Он автоматически скачивается в папку с проектом и уже от туда читается, и сохраняет данные в память через JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>().

Помогите добавить новые данные, и сохранить.
Пытался сохранить 2-мя способами, но вылезают ошибки.

Сам JSON:

[image: Сам JSON:]

Ошибка способа 1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка способа 2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените картинки кодом и примером данных как текст.

Comment: "от туда читается, и сохраняет данные в память через JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()" - код, который это делает, мы должны вообразить у нас в голове?

Comment: Да там на картинке видно, всё просто, автор судя по всему не знает, что счёт элементов массива начинается с `0`.

Comment: лол. Там не картинка.... Это скрин с сайта -_-

Comment: "Да там на картинке видно, всё просто, автор судя по всему не знает, что счёт элементов массива начинается с 0" Ну. 0, 1,2,3. И я пытаюсь создать 4-ый.

Comment: не 4й, а с индексом 4. То есть в массиве будут элементы с индексами  0,1,2 и 4. Место элемента с индексом 3 займет пустой объект. Т.е. 5 элементов в массиве на 4

Comment: `m.json[4] = new JSO...` это вы обратились уже к пятому элементу массива, которого нет в принципе, там места для него нет. Создайте новый массив с большем количеством "ячеек", добавьте туда старый массив и свои новые значения...

Comment: У меня их 4. (в базе). Хочу создать 5-ый. Создаю с индексом 4. Что не так???

Comment: Маты запрещены что-ли? Ясн...

Comment: Ещё + ошибка:
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Airline.R.JSON.json.get[] было null.

Comment: Почитайте о том, как [правильно оформлять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) вопросы.

Comment: Уважаемый, мне кажется вам еще рано работать с API, JSON и др. Изучите для начала массивы, что это. Изучите основы в целом и как работает язык C#. У вас сразу такие вопросы пропадут и станет намного легче!

Answer (score 0):

```
m.json = new JSON[4];
```

это создает массив из четырех элементов с индексами 0, 1, 2 и 3. Места для элемента с индексом 4  в этом массиве нет.

А в этом - есть:

```
m.json = new JSON[5];
m.json[4] = new JSON() { ...
```

Comment: Интересно, сколько же вопросов было задано из-за не прочитанных текстов исключений? =)

Comment: Уже около года имею опыт программирования и до сих пор имею привычку не дочитывая сообщение исключения бежать исправлять то место, которое мне кажется проблемным. Эх...

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSON>(Form1.JS.js());

JSON mm = new JSON();

int test = length + 1;

mm.json = new JSO[test];

for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  mm.json[i] = new JSO()
  {
    Group = m.json[i].Group,
    EMail = m.json[i].EMail,
    Password = m.json[i].Password,
    Firstname = m.json[i].Firstname,
    Lastname = m.json[i].Lastname,
    Birthday = m.json[i].Birthday,
    Activity = m.json[i].Activity
  };

}

mm.json[i++] = new JSO()
{
  Group = "User",
  EMail = textBox1.Text,
  Password = textBox2.Text,
  Firstname = textBox5.Text,
  Lastname = textBox6.Text,
  Birthday = dateTimePicker1.Text,
  Activity = "true"
};

File.WriteAllText("Accountss.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mm));
```